# Stored Procedure Throwing Error But Updating Record

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I've got a stored procedure that will update a flag based on a county code, a URL or a combination of both. For instance, County 03 might have these two records:

```
county_code = 03
webservice_type_id = 1
webservice_URL = http://192.168.100.3/A
```

And

```
county_code = 03
webservice_type_id = 2
webservice_URL = http://192.168.100.3/B
```

And if I want to use my stored procedure to enable/disable the flag, I should be able to run:

```
execute dbo.usp_webservice_change_status
@enable = 1
@county_code = '03'
@webserviceURL = http://192.168.100.3/B
```

and update only the record that matches both condidtions.  But what I am seeing is that the stored procedure updates the records for the county but throws the RAISERROR statement in the stored procedure.

For example, here are my current records:

[image]

And when I run the stored procedure:

[image]

I am getting the following:

[image]

But when I look at the records again, I see that they have been updated:
[image]

Here is the code for the stored procedure.  Could anyone help me understand where I am wrong?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_webservice_change_status]
    @enable AS BIT,
    @county_code AS CHAR(2) = NULL,
    @webserviceURL AS VARCHAR(4000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @enable IS NULL
        RAISERROR ('The value for @enable should not be null', 15, 1);

    IF ( @county_code IS NULL AND @webserviceURL IS NULL )
        RAISERROR ('The value for @county_code and @webserviceURL cannot both be null', 15, 1);

    -- Update for County Code Only
    IF (@county_code IS NOT NULL AND @webserviceURL IS NULL )
        UPDATE dbo.webservice_config
        SET [enable] = @enable,
            comments = CASE
                           WHEN @enable = 1 
                              THEN 'Enabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                              ELSE 'Disabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                       END
        WHERE county_code = @county_code;

    -- Update for Webservice URL only
    ELSE IF ( @county_code IS NULL AND @webserviceURL IS NOT NULL )
        UPDATE dbo.webservice_config
        SET [enable] = @enable,
            comments = CASE
                          WHEN @enable = 1 
                             THEN 'Enabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                             ELSE 'Disabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                       END    
        WHERE webservice_URL = @webserviceURL;

    -- Update for both County Code and Webservice URL - but only if the records match
    ELSE IF (@county_code IS NOT NULL AND @webserviceURL IS NOT NULL )
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT) < 1
            RAISERROR('Nothing Updated Due to Non Matching Records', 15, 1);

        UPDATE dbo.webservice_config
        SET [enable] = @enable,
            comments = CASE
                          WHEN @enable = 1 
                             THEN 'Enabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                             ELSE 'Disabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                       END
        WHERE (county_code = @county_code 
               AND webservice_URL = @webserviceURL);
END;
```

Comment: well, of course, you are first raising the error, and then run an `UPDATE`

Comment: OK - I thought raising the error would prevent the update from running.

Comment: So, you actually wanted to not update the table unless one of the parameters were `null`?

Comment: No - if one of the parameters was NULL, it should still update. But if both parameters are provided, I want to make sure they match an existing record in the database. I will try to clarify in the original question.

Comment: But then your `RAISERROR` makes no sense at all

Comment: Probably right - I was just trying to come up with a way to make sure the parameters matched an existing record and that was what I came up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I used to generate the correct response:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_webservice_change_status]
@enable AS BIT,
@county_code AS CHAR(2) = NULL,
@webserviceURL AS VARCHAR(4000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Count INT = ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.webservice_config WHERE county_code = @county_code AND webservice_URL = @webserviceURL );

....

ELSE IF ( @county_code IS NOT NULL AND @webserviceURL IS NOT NULL )
         IF @Count > 0
             UPDATE dbo.webservice_config
             SET [enable] = @enable,
                 comments = CASE
                                WHEN @enable = 1 THEN 'Enabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                                ELSE 'Disabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                            END
             WHERE ( county_code = @county_code AND webservice_URL = @webserviceURL );

         ELSE
             RAISERROR ('Nothing Updated Due to Non Matching Records', 15, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

In your last ELSE IF where you are checking that both params are not null, the next line you use

```
IF (@@ROWCOUNT) < 1
```

But I don't see where you are running a query to see if there is a matching record for the provided params.

I would think you would want to run something like

```
IF(SELECT count(1) FROM dbo.webservice_config) <> 1
  RAISEERROR
ELSE
  Do your update
```

Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks Paul - I'll mark it correct because based off your answer, I was able to rewrite the SQL to make the proc work as intended.